# How to inject the full request path in Spring @RestController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How can I inject the complete subpath in a Spring `@RestController`?

In my example, I want `subpaths=/test/sub/path` being injected

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/v1/{subpaths}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object handle(@PathVariable String subpaths) {
        //this is not called for /v1/test/sub/path
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, rest controllers shouldn't return a view, they should return xml, json, etc. Second, if you want to capture 3 path segments, you should create 3 path variables, one for each segment. Alternatively, if some of the segments aren't dynamic, you can skip the path variable and hard-code those segments.

Comment: Well it's just an example, or course I will return `json` here. I don't know the length of the subpath beforehand, therefore I have to capture the full subpath. I also don't need the path segments as individual variables, simple the query string with all subpaths in one String.

Comment: I cannot share the code as it is a proprietary piece of software (not mine), but I have created custom custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that was able to extract UNIX file path from prefixed URL where by prefix in your case would be `/v1/`. Mapping itself must contain wildcard `/v1/**` so it will match everything. Then using `AntPathMatcher` it is done out of the box. It takes just a couple of lines. It is used then as `@GetMapping(value="/v1/**)
public void method(@MyWildcardVar String segments);`

Comment: If you want a single entrypoint for ALL subpaths , you can just capture everything `/v1/**` and then later within the method just get the request url and lastly string after `v1/`(split after v1/) is your subpath.

Comment: @Rambler how would I access the request url inside the method?

Comment: @membersound added a sample.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively if the idea is to have a single entry point , we can just capture everything and later just extract subpath.
The following illustrates the same :

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/v1/parentPath/**", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object handle(@RequestParam(name = "myParam") String myParam,HttpServletRequest request) {
        //Get the complete url
        String url=request.getRequestURL();
        String[] paths=url.split("parentPath/");
        //paths[1] is the desired subPath
 
        //Provides URI
        // example : /context-path/v1/parentPath/subPath
        String uri=request.getRequestURI();

        //Returns query string, ex: test=abc&page=1
        String queryString=request.getQueryString();

        //Returns query parameters as map,Includes both query and ported form data
        Map<String, String[]> parameterMap=request.getParameterMap();

    }
}
```

**HttpServletRequest** : is injected automatically by Spring.(Will try to find some documentation and add it here)

Just to be safe added parentPath to ensure that we do not capture ALL of the requests under v1

Comment: I forgot the I also need the query string, if present. So I just need *anything* beside the domain...

Comment: @membersound If i understand your requirement ,  you can just use the `getRequestURI()` method.This will exclude any domain path.It will include the application's context-path , which i think you do need.

Comment: Unfortunately `getRequestURI()` does **not** contain the query params, eg `context-path/v1/parentPath/subPath?param=val`.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood , you still have @RequestParam for that.See updated answer.
Not related but do checkout \@RequestHeader and \@RequestBody too.

Comment: I neither know the names or count of the query parameters beforehand, and also not the subpath. I have to get them generically, not by fixed `@RequestParam`. That's why I'm asking for to get the "whole url".

Comment: @membersound Checkout : getQueryString and getParameterMap methods of HttpServletRequest.In essence HttpServletRequest has every info abt the call.

Comment: Okay, I hoped there was simply a `getFullUrl()` method that get's me the complete string from start to end, not having to aggregate myself. But as that's not possible, if course I can join `.getRequestURI() + '?' + getRequestString()`, though that still doesn't feel right.